# ruby on rails - translate id to name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two objects ingredient & origin.
each ingredient has an origin so in the ingredient I have origin_id
the view displays

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @ingredient.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Origin:</b>
  <%= @ingredient.origin_id %>
</p>
```

I want to display the origin name and not the ID.
How do I bring the name to the display?

EDIT: class ingredient is declared as follows

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
  belongs_to :origin

  attr_accessible :name, :origin_id
end
```

class origin

```
class Origin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare in `Ingredient`class:

```
belongs_to :origin
```

After that, you can use

```
<%= @ingredient.origin.name %>
```

See the [Rail Relation Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (`belongs_to` and `has_one` association in your case)

Comment: I get - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @perry it means that `@ingredient.origin` is `nil`, certainly because `@ingredient.origin_id` is `nil`, or do not match an id in the table 'origins'